# Commands - Select entity not in volume

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I can select entities (or players) who are in a volume easily.

```
@e[x=0,dx=20,y=0,dy=256,z=20,dz=1]
```

How do I select all entities who are *not* in a given volume?

---

I'm giving players in a certain room a tag, doing stuff with the tag, and want to remove it when they leave.

Comment: You're already using tags, why not just use `tag=!`?

Comment: If I'm giving players in the room tag `foo`, what do you mean?

Comment: `@a[tag=!foo]` .

Comment: @FabianRöling Yep, dupe. Only googled for "volume", not "area".

Comment: `/tag @a[tag=!foo] remove foo` seems redundant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94429/discussion-between-sigstackfault-and-fabian-roling).